# How to use set WindowsLookandFeel with default font size when preferences set to 125%

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

We have a client swing application that looks fine on Windows using

```
String look = javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(look);
```

except when the user preferences are set to use 125% or 150% font scaling, which causes the components on our dialogs to overflow as the individual components expand within the frames. We're using the Netbeans GUI builder which I guess does not use layout managers which expand with the font scaling.

My question is whether we can use the Windows look and feel but ensure that the font setting is always set to 100%, so it behaves more like other themes (Metal, Nimbus) which do not respond to the font size change, but in other respects uses the sysem look and feel?

I think we can set the font size on each individual font property of UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults(), but if we did this would it work?

Comment: Are your components really expanding?  If they are, the code is probably using layout managers correctly, and all you need to do is size each window using `pack()` instead of hard-coding its bounds.

Comment: So you want to ignore the user's settings, and behave like other things that ignore the user's settings?  monitors are getting bigger and bigger and bigger and higher resolution, and this seems like the wrong way to try to solve the problem.

Comment: No actually I don't think the components are expanding, for instance it seems that most buttons are not expanding and therefore the expanded label text is too large for the button and is truncated. The behaviour is erratic with most text being enlarged, like menus and labels, with other text remaining the original size. Also, some dialogs created with the GUI builder do resize, whicle others do not, so I'm lookng for an interim solution that looks good while we iron out all the isssues.

Comment: If you look at this applet, when set to Windows L&F, it does NOT resize to the preferred font: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/  Is this because it's running as an applet?

Comment: You can change the size of the font for all components to keep them small. Yet your app becomes less usable for the user as UI is hard to see. So the proper way is to use layout managers and `pack()`: this way UI will scale according to user's preferences.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "user preferences are set to use 125% or 150% font scaling"?